How to create instance of a Pydantic model with subset fields
This is the model
class UsersInformationModel(BaseDataModel):
    id: Optional[int] = None
    is_vip: bool = False
    creation_tag: Optional[dict] = None  # JSON field mapped to a dictionary
    user_id: int  # Not nullable
    created_at: Optional[datetime] = None
    updated_at: Optional[datetime] = None
    branch_id: Optional[int] = None
    setting: Optional[dict] = None  # JSON field mapped to a dictionary
    vip_type: int = 0
    medication_history: Optional[bool] = None
    other_disease: Optional[str] = None
    tobacco_alcohol_use: Optional[bool] = None
    consumed_medications: Optional[str] = None
    consumed_medications_amount: Optional[str] = None

and BaseDataModel
from pydantic import BaseModel, PrivateAttr, root_validator
from typing import Dict, Any


class BaseDataModel(BaseModel):
    _explicit_fields: set = PrivateAttr(default_factory=set)

    class Config:
        # Pydantic settings
        populate_by_name = True
        exclude_unset = True

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def validate_fields(cls, values):
        # This ensures that only explicitly set fields are retained in the model
        for field in values.copy():
            if field not in cls.__fields__:
                del values[field]
        return values

    def dict(self, **kwargs):
        # Ensure fields are excluded if not set (only non-None fields are included)
        return super().model_dump(exclude_unset=True, **kwargs)

The problem is when I write:
    data = {
        'user_id': self.current_user.id,
        'medication_history': self.data.medication_history,
        'other_disease': self.data.other_disease,
        'tobacco_alcohol_use': self.data.tobacco_alcohol_use,
        'consumed_medications': self.data.consumed_medications,
        'branch_id': None,
        'consumed_medications_amount': self.data.consumed_medications_amount,
    }
    data = UsersInformationModel(**data)
    data_dict = data.dict()

The data contains all of the model's fields and sets the non-mentioned fields to None, but the data_dict is OK and only contains fields included in the data.
How can I change BaseDataModel so that data only contains the mentioned fields? No matter if the value is None, I want it to have only explicitly included fields.

You probably want to use exclude_none https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/exporting_models/

@YaakovBressler some fields may be None, If I explicitly set None, it must be included and get None value. Just imagine the case where you want to use an instance of Model to update a record in Database. So some fields may be None (Null)
